# Is the sentence "Indian guy cooks so well that Gordon Ramsay calls his mother to judge the food" ambiguous?

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context, pronouns, idiomatic-language

I came across a YouTube video with the title "[Indian guy cooks so well that Gordon Ramsay calls his mother to judge the food](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YRQxLeU1CbA)."

I thought Gordon Ramsay called his own mother, not the contestant's mother. However, in the video, Gordon Ramsay actually calls the contestant's mother.

How do people understand the meaning without ambiguity? I mean, can native speakers understand this well?

Comment: It's ambiguous to native speakers also.

Comment: "Headlinese" is often ambiguous, simply because they're trying to use a few words as possible. Sometimes it's even *deliberately* ambiguous because the writers want to be curious and watch the video to figure out, for example, whose mother was called.

Comment: adding for emphasis …  calls *his **own** mother* …, should help clear up the ambiguity as to whose mother (Ramsay's) we're referring to but there's no guarantee.

Comment: **His** simply means "belonging to a male person", and doesn't change with subject or object, so yes, it can always be ambiguous.  Consider "John gave Bob his hat" - we have no way of knowing whether it was John's hat or Bob's hat.

Comment: It's ambiguous. But if you asked people, the tendency would be to attach the verb to the nearest subject. Meaning it implies it was Gordon Ramsay's mother.